# JQUERY caching if Back-button after posting to form - JQUERY fadeIn still visable

Tags: jquery, caching, browser-cache, back-button

I am posting a form at the end of a JQUERY fadeIn.

- When the user hits submit - a DIV '**SWITCHING_SCREENS**' - with a
  message in it, is faded in via JQUERY and covers the form page.
- Once that div is fully faded in - javascript then posts the form to
  another page.

Javascript:

```
    Theform = document.getElementById('customers_form');

    $('#SWITCHING_SCREENS').fadeIn('slow', function(){
        Theform.submit();
    });
```

This is all working well, and I have no problem with the submitting or anything else.
But on the chance that the user then hits the **browser back button (firefox)** - the SWITCHING_SCREENS is still visible.

I have seen back-button caching of form elements - but expected the JQUERY to reset on back-button. Or I just didn't expect it to cache.

- **It seems as though it has cached?**
- **Has the JQUERY cached this state of the DIV?**

I have tried:

Javascript:

```
Theform = document.getElementById('customers_form');

$('#SWITCHING_SCREENS').fadeIn('slow', function(){
    Theform.submit();
    $('#SWITCHING_SCREENS').hide();
});
```

and this does remedy the caching of the DIV in the 'fadeIn' state when the browser back-button is used...

But it also removes the DIV **before** the page actually switches to the posted page. I want the div to remain visible while the page is posting to the next page - and to be gone if the visitor hits the back button.

This seems to only be happening in Firefox.

Thank you.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [.unload()](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) it doesn't specifically intercepts **back button** but any event that **unloads** current page. It can be anything **clicking on link**, **forward button** or **back button** based on the browser.

```
$(window).unload( function () { $('#SWITCHING_SCREENS').hide(); });
```

> The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates
>   away from the page. This could mean one of many things. The user could
>   have clicked on a link to leave the page, or typed in a new URL in the
>   address bar. The forward and back buttons will trigger the event.
>   Closing the browser window will cause the event to be triggered. Even
>   a page reload will first create an unload event.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code on pageload.

```
$(document).ready(function({  
    $('#SWITCHING_SCREENS').hide();
    ..... rest of your code will go here.........
}));
```

Comment: This answer should work, it seems that FF is caching the CSS stored in the element from the jQuery fadeIn. By hiding the element on document ready event you are removing the CSS from fadeIn cached or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that jQuery has cached anything, it's that the browser cached the state of the page as the user last saw it.  This is normal and some say preferable behavior.  For example, if you scroll to the bottom of a page and then click a link (that takes you to a new page) and then hit the back button, the browser might even take you to the bottom of the page again, just where you left it.

So I would suggest something like:

```
$('#SWITCHING_SCREENS').fadeIn('slow', function(){
    $(window).unload( function () { $('#SWITCHING_SCREENS').hide(); });
    Theform.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hey im not 100% sure what your trying to do but this may help but it sounds like you want the user to be on the form page  1. hit submit  2. wait for form  3. then transferred to another page

```
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){ 

        $.post(
            $(this).attr('href'),
            {url: "url",
             dataType: "html",
            },
            function( data )
            {

        $('#content').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith(data).fadeIn(); 

         });
        }
        );
        return false;
    });
```

this will submit the form load new page from server without recording the url if you hit back or foward it reloads the page only to show the form

php side

```
<?php
// Determing if this is an include or ajax call
if( $_POST["url"] = $_POST['url'] ){ ?>

<div id="content">
new page data
</div>

<?php  }else{ ?>


 <div id="content">

your form </div>

<?php } ?>
```

this my be more of a "hack" im sorry new to jquery.